# Repeating delimiters and extracting the string between those

Tags: python, html, substring, text-extraction

I am fairly new to Python and to regular expressions, and am looking to extract information from an html file.

Assume the following is a line given in the html file (since html doesn't "see" whitespace, our example is on the same line)

```
<td (some possible parameters)> EXTRACT_THIS </td> <td (some possible parameters)> ALSO_EXTRACT_THIS </td>
```

In my current code:

```
with open(myInput, 'r') as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
        line = line.strip()

        if line != '':

            m = re.findall('<td.*>(.*?)</td>', line)
            if m:
                #strip() again
                print(m)
```

This will only print:

```
['ALSO_EXTRACT_THIS']
```

instead of my desired

```
['EXTRACT_THIS', 'ALSO_EXTRACT_THIS']
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I've looked into it and it seems that this is a way for to extract multiple substrings with repeating delimiters.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but Regex is not the best tool to extract from HTML.

Comment: Well I'd like to extract the information that is between <td> and </td>, with which I will print out to a another file, of course by using a for-loop to go through the list created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `<td.*>` will match the longest string it can, which is `<td (some possible parameters)> EXTRACT_THIS </td> <td (some possible parameters)>`.

You should use non-greedy quantifier for the `<td>` too:

```
'<td.*?>(.*?)</td>'
```